# AWS - Additional SSH User with cloud-init. No Reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel7, amazon-linux

I am able to successfully provision linux ssh users via cloud-init upon initial startup using this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-user-account-cloud-init-user-data/

The issue I am facing is that every time I need to add or remove users, I need to shut down the machine to modify to user-data script. How would I go about creating and removing users while reducing downtime?

If I manually add users (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/), will those users be removed when the instance restarts and runs the startup script?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about what you're trying to do?  The `user-data` scripts are run once when the machine is provisioned and never again.  Without some centralized user management service (i.e. LDAP) users are managed on a machine by machine basis - if you add or remove them from one they will not be automatically be added or removed from the other machines.

Comment: I am trying to setup linux user accounts on individual linux machines but do not have a centralized user management service. I was hoping to use the user-data yaml configuration to bootstrap approximately 20 users to save me the trouble of setting up each user manually and bypass the need to have a custom shell script to do this work. The user-data scripts work great, however thinking long term, I will have situations where I need to add additional users and remove them from each machine. Just trying to find the right approach to do so without having to implement any sort of centralized mgmt.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use EC2 launch templates. Very easy to setup and easy to clone to different instance sizes and classes. Pretty slick how I use them with user data to control environment variables for dev, stage, prod use too!